# I have Compilation error when i use CenterAlignedTopAppBar in my code

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Hi I'm new in jetpack compose this is my code

```
@Composable
fun WoofApp() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "hi") }) // ERROR
        }
    ) { it ->
        LazyColumn(contentPadding = it) {
            items(dogs) {
                DogItem(
                    dog = it,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.padding_small))
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have CompilationErrorException in android studio and it says

e: (above ERROR) This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.

I tried TopAppBar() instead of CenterAlignedTopAppBar() but still got the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the **material 3 API** which is still **experimental** so you have to this `annotation` on your composable function     `@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)`
so your function should be like this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun WoofApp() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "hi") }) // ERROR
        }
    ) { it ->
        //some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Befor all functions and even befor MainActivity class you need mentioned:

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
```

Like this:

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun WoofTopAppBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) { ...
```

and this:

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {  ...
```

and import it

```
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).